# How to change pods ACT upload dir

Tags: pods-framework

I am trying to change the upload dir of files when it is uploaded through the front end using pods.

How can i check if the upload is coming from a Advanced Content Type using pods?

template-view-page.php

```
$pod_name = pods_v( 0, 'url');
$pods = pods( $pod_name, $slug );
$fields = array( 'name', 'file' ); 
echo $pods->form( $fields );
```

functions.php

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'change_upload_dir');
function change_upload_dir( $param ){

$pod_name = pods_v( 0, 'url');
if ($pod_name == "paperwork") {
    $mydir = '/paperwork';
}

else {
    $mydir = '/notpaperwork';
}

$param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mydir;
$param['url'] = $param['url'] . $mydir;

return $param;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer here is you can't check whether the upload is coming from a Pods Advanced Content Type, especially since the media that gets uploaded has no post_id associated to it (it's not a post at that point).

The longer answer is that you can still customize this if your file upload field is using plupload itself, not the normal media library input. You will want to hook into the `pods_upload_handle` filter to `add_filter` for your special `upload_dir` callback. Just make sure you return null on the `pods_upload_handle` filter to let Pods continue handling the upload. The `pods_upload_handle` filter passes 5 arguments:

```
$custom_handler = null, $file_arg = 'Filedata', $post_id = $params->post_id, $params, $field
```

You would want to check if `$params->pod` (the pod id) is set and if so use it to check if it is your ACT pod. If it matches your ACT pod, then you can add your `upload_dir` filter.

Using this way, you can be sure you are adding it only for the ACT intended.